# Disable auto layout animation for one view

Tags: ios

I'm sorry, I don't know a better title.

The issue:

I've got one `UITableViewCell` with auto layout, the default height in the nib is 300. 300 is the correct size for one of my `UIViewControllers`.

I'm using a `UINavigationController` inside a container view, beneath the container view is a `UIView` called `FooterView`.

In the container view are two `UIViewControllers`; `VC1` and `VC2`.

When I'm pushing `VC2` onto `VC1`, I'm also changing the height of FooterView with it's `NSLayoutConstraint` height constant.

I'm doing this inside a animation block, with `[self.view setNeedsLayout];`

I'm setting the height for the `UITableViewCell` inside `VC2` to 200.

Now the problem is that when I'm transitioning from `VC1` to `VC2` you also see the `UITableViewCell` being animated from 300 to 200.

My guess is that this is because of the animation block. I've tested it by removing the animation and the cell didn't animate (as expected).

Is there any way to stop this animation chaining?

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: Do you really need to call `setNeedsLayout`? You can specify what view to animate and what not.

Comment: You mean by animating the frame? The thing is that the bottom constraint of the container view is linked to the top constraint of the FooterView, will that animate as well when I change the frame of the FooterView with an animation?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your situation. Having a screenshot will be good.

Comment: Sorry for writing it poorly, I couldn't attach a screenshot because it's a project for a client.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All I needed to do was to override `layoutSubviews` inside the cell:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [super layoutSubviews];
        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _shadowView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_shadowView.bounds].CGPath;
    }];
}
```